# How the form procedures related to the database procedures in oracle forms. Where they are related for dependency projects

Tags: oracleforms

For project to project dependencies, how are form procedures interlinked with db procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form procedures are not interlinked with the db procedures.

Comment: then how can be the dependency for one project to other.